# Asp Net Boilerplate - MultiTenancy, Module Zero & Additional Modules

Tags: asp.net-core, module, multi-tenant, aspnetboilerplate

We started developing our product using the AspNetBoilerplate & Module Zero template. So we have the canonical

1. `Acme.Product.Application`
2. `Acme.Product.Core`
3. `Acme.Product.EntityFrameworkCore`
4. `Acme.Product.Migrator`
5. `Acme.Product.Web.Core`
6. `Acme.Product.Web.Host` (w/ Angular SPA)

In the Asp Net Boilerplate & Module Zero documentation, it indicates

1. That it is possible to develop as Saas architecture by using the multitenancy infrastructure (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy).
2. That it is possible to create a modular application (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Module-System).

We could not find any documentation or questions on SO on **how to enable multitenancy for additional modules**.

Say we decided to divide our domain logic in separate assemblies/modules:

7. `Acme.Product.Accounting`
8. `Acme.Product.HR`

Both modules would depend on **Acme.Product.Core** (which enables multitenancy).

```
namespace Acme.Product.Accounting {
  [DependsOn(typeof(Acme.Product.Core.ProductModule))]
  public class Module : AbpModule {

  }
}

namespace Acme.Product.HR {
  [DependsOn(typeof(Acme.Product.Core.ProductModule))]
  public class Module : AbpModule {

  }
}
```

Then, in the `Acme.Product.HR` module :

```
namespace Acme.Product.HR.Domain.Models{
   public class Employee : Entity<Guid>, IMustHaveTenant {
   }
}
```

Do we have to enable multitenancy for `Acme.Product.Accounting.Module` & `Acme.Product.HR.Module` as well in the module configuration in order to use the multitenancy architecture defined in the core `Acme.Product.Core.ProductModule` ?

```
Configuration.MultiTenancy.IsEnabled = true;
```

Also, do we have to define the multitenancy entities as well ?

```
Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.Tenant = typeof(Tenant);
Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.Role = typeof(Role);
Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.User = typeof(User);
```

Has anyone successfully implemented such a scenario where additional modules would be able to use the multitenancy infrastructure (dynamic queries, checks, etc.) ?

Comment: You only need to initialize it once, in your **.Core** module.

Comment: `Configuration.MultiTenancy.IsEnabled = true; ` is an application-wide config.